# "THREAD EXEC BREAKPOINT" issue in my code trying to add a document into firestore subcollection

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add a document into a subcollection in a document found in my firestore database via a function. But unfortunately it causes a **thread exec** error which I clearly can't tell what the issue is.

I have used this same method of proceeding in other functions of this type using the documents unique id as point of reference to a particular document. But I can't tell why this particular case bugs

Code bug :

```
 func addComment(from data:[String:Any], completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()){
        db.collection("Events").document((event?.uid)!).collection("Comments").addDocument(data: data) { (error) in // This line causes Thread Breakpoint
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

        }
        completion(true)
    }
```

It should add a document with an auto-generated id set with the data parsed in
[image: Thread breakpoint error]

Comment: This `.document((event?.uid)!)` is dangerous and likely where the problem is. Please safely work with optionals to project your code - force unwapping them is a slippery slope.

Comment: @Jay Wouldn't the error then be `Attempt to force unwrap a nil` (or something like that. Can't really remember the wording)

Comment: I think the problem is with the data Value. Firebase fails to deserialize the `[String: Any]` dictionary since maybe your `Any` has an type whose decoding is not handled or `Any` is not supported at all? Try writing a simple `String` instead to determine if thats the issue.

Comment: @jms You are probably correct. I didn't notice the function was `.addDocument`. That will throw and err if data is nil or Any is something other than what Firebase supports.

Comment: Hope you got it working. And on a side note, I support @Jays answer 100%. Don't force unwrap optionals. Use the beautiful `if let` or `guard` statements to handle them (they are one of the absolute beauties in the language). Or consider making uid a non-optional.